# Why can't I access the update method in dbset?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am creating a class for my repositories to inherit. And I put some methods that are common, one of them, Update.

But I have this error `DbSet does not contain a definition for Update`

```
public abstract class AggregateRepository<TEntity> : IAggregateRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : AggregateEntity, new ()
    {
        protected readonly MyDbContext DbContext;
        protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

        protected AggregateRepository(MyDbContext dbContext)
        {
            DbContext = dbContext;
            DbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual async Task Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            DbSet.Update(entity); //ERROR
        }
}
```

If there is no entry for an Update, how should I do to update an entity in the database?

Comment: you simply change the values of it's properties and you call `SubmitChanges()` in the end. Every entity is tracked in the background, so the system will know on which part of the data it has to call update

Comment: So, I can't do it, in this aggregate. Am I right?

Comment: Or do I have to call Add with this generic entity?

Comment: The question "how to update an entity" is too broad. It depends on how you work (connected/disconnected) and all kinds of preferences.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, it is. But my question is not about "how to update an entity". My reference code is only the generic part, because I would like this update to be common to all these entities.  The entity must already arrive there ready to be inserted in the base.

Comment: Still leaves a lot of questions. For one, why do you need the update method anyway? EF manages change tracking itself. And, only this entity or also nested ones? Whole entities or only changed properties? ...

Comment: " The entity must already arrive there ready to be inserted in the base" there is a big difference between "update" and "insert" you need to be clear on this one. for insert there is a special method. `InsertOnSubmit`

Comment: @MongZhu my mistake. I to update, not insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the entity is being tracked by the context (i.e. the entity to be updated is fetched from the context prior to update and AsNoTracking() is not used), then the update is a simple call of `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync`

```
public virtual async Task Update(TEntity entity)
{
    // In case entity is being tracked.
    if (entity == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
    return DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

else you need to track the entity first and then save changes.

```
public virtual async Task TrackAndUpdate(TEntity entity)
{
    // In case AsNoTracking is used while retrieving entity or entity is not tracked.
    Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    return DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Based upon the requirement appropriate method can be called to update the entity.

Comment: This is a very limited answer or even incorrect. The first method saves *all* changes in a context, not just the entity as on would expect from the method signature (and which wouldn't be possible using EF). The second method disregards nested entities and hence may lead to exceptions or even incorrect database content.

Comment: Hi, can you provide some example or documentation surrounding it please. We have that implementation in one of our component and I am very much interested to fix it before it causes any serious trouble. Moreover, the component has been working for quite some time without any issues.

Comment: It's a very broad subject, really, for example, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2016/april/data-points-handling-the-state-of-disconnected-entities-in-ef). That's why the question ("how should I do to update an entity in the database?") was closed as being too broad. You need to know all parameters to come to an appropriate solution. What works in your case may be insufficient for others.

Comment: Thank you for the article. I will take a look at it.